# Gin CORS not adding to response

Tags: go, cors, go-gin

I'm using golang gin and I got this error

[image]

I know this is a CORS error and I fixed it in NodeJS but this time I'm working with golang and hence not able to fix it.

I got around this package `https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors` and modified my code

```
r := gin.Default()
r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:5173"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"PUT", "PATCH", "POST"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length", "Content-Type"},
    AllowFiles:       true,
    AllowCredentials: true,
    AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
        return origin == "http://localhost:5173"
    },
}))
```

`

But the thing is that this error still coming up.

Comment: In your server you have: `AllowHeaders: []string{"Origin"}`. The browser error says:  `Request header field content-type is not allowed`. The browser is correct, your server CORS setting allows only `Origin` and no other header in the request.

Comment: As per Mozilla, Access-Control-Allow-Headers is used to tell which headers can be sent during a request while Access-Control-Expose-Headers is used to tell which headers are available for use by scripts in the browser

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

the browser is complaining because the server doesn't allow, in the Allowed Headers, the header 'Content-type'. add this header in the list of allowed headers then the CORS will stop complain.

Answer (score 0):

You seem confused about the purpose of [the `ExposeHeaders` field](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-contrib/cors#Config.ExposeHeaders) in that `cors.Config` struct. I can understand your confusion: neither the field name—`ExposeResponseHeaders` would, at the expense of conciseness, arguably be clearer—nor its documentation are particularly elucidating...

The `ExposeHeaders` struct  field dictates which *response* header names will be listed in the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, which instruct the browser to let the client access the values of those response headers. But, AFAICT, that's not what you want to do here. Instead, you want to allow requests that include a header named `Content-Type`. To do that, you need to modify the value of the [`AllowHeaders` struct field](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-contrib/cors#Config.AllowHeaders) in your CORS config like so:

```golang
AllowHeaders: []string{"Content-Type"},
```

Note that, [per the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header), allowing `Origin` as a request header in your CORS configuration is never necessary, simply because that header is managed by the browser rather than by the client.

Also, your use of the `AllowOriginFunc` is redundant. `AllowOrigins` is enough for your current needs.